# Play iis smooth streaming (.ism) in android

Tags: android, video, stream, streaming, smoothing

Did android device supports playing iis smooth streaming (.ism)?

I'm trying to play a video stream in this format, and get an error about "Bad parameter"

Comment: Hi did you manage to work it out ? Exoplayer? Doesnt seem to work with mediaplayer even with .ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl) format..;(

Comment: Nope I did not. Sorry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

Soo I will answer my question... the answer is: No.

The native player (for example "VideoView") doesn't support playing iis smooth streaming (.ism).

Answer (score 0):

One way of accompishing this is buying a separate player such as ViualOn.

A separate trick is using a transmuxer such as Universal Streaming to make a format suitable for Androids.